# Delphi printing primer

Tags: delphi, printing

I need to add printing capabilities to an app and I have been looking around for information about printing. Logical/physical sizes, dpi, font scaling, etc, lots to digest since I never programmed printing into any app before.

Are there any sites that would offer a primer on the topics of page sizes, margins and all the other elements required to understand printing on Windows? I've been looking around for a while but what I find is either cryptic or years old...

I've been playing around with TPrinter, but I would like to build solid printing functionalities and understand what I'm doing better.

Using a report solution is not an option, even though I'm sure it would provide better results much sooner.

Comment: So what it is years old? It doesn't have to be bad. I don't think that there were some major changes in the world of printers and printig since years. You can print on the canvas like you were drawing on the canvas. What exacly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Wodzu: Printing on a printer canvas like on any other is the lazy way to do it. Much better IMHO to set a mapping mode (like `MM_LOMETRIC` or `MM_HIMETRIC`) in order to not have to deal with varying printer resolutions. Unfortunately there is no support for that in the VCL, so direct calls to the Windows API are necessary.

Comment: @mghie but still he is drawing like he would be drawing on any other canvas with the difference that metrcis has changed. I've meant methods which actually perfrom drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two links to get you started:

[Printing with TPrinter](http://delphi.about.com/od/tprinterprinting/Printing_with_TPrinter.htm)
[Printing via the TPrinter Canvas](http://mc-computing.com/Languages/Delphi/Printing.html)

Comment: I managed to find all the information I needed, thank you for posting these links.

I took the time to note the fact that I couldn't use reporting solutions in my original question. This is due to software constraints, budget constraints, requirements and evaluation of several reporting solutions...

Reinventing the wheel might take time away from the core of your project. But if done right, that wheel will fit perfectly where its supposed to fit...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking too lowlevel.

Try looking at the build reporting tools (Rave or whatever is in your product).
Personally i am using a product called Report Builder from Digital Metaphors.

But if you want to do the lowlevel stuff lot og good information can be found at [efg's computer lab - printing](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Printing/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have done things a variety of ways in the past, including the "hard way" with TPrinter.  In fact, I recently had to do that again to run a special inventory label printer.

On the other hand, sometimes you are better off taking work others have done and using it for your benefit.  I agree that ReportSmith isn't so great, and also it's Delphi (and Windows) specific.  Using Excel or Word has those limitations, plus the fact that the user has to actually have them installed.

One thing I have done to make printing easy for some simple applications is just to generate an HTML file and call the user's web browser, then they can print it.  HTML tables can be created relatively easily for numerical data, and you can include photos, etc. as well.  This works well for some applications, and works on every platform where a web browser is installed.  The downside, of course, is that HTML isn't the most precise layout language.

Comment: +1 for output to html. I then used to use pbear's htmlview to print it (rather than send it to browser) however last time I looked htmlview hadn't been updated to work with unicode and therefore didn't print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Delphi you´re using is important.  A number of Delphis came with print engines like ReportSmith (ugh).  Another option thinking laterally is to use MS Word as a print engine.  I´ve hooked into instances of Word & Excel before & utilised their functionality.  As to raw printing using TPrinter or the print method of TForm you´d have to be pretty desperate.  I seem to recall the Pacheo / Texeira Delphi books coming with a pretty good overview so you might want to see if you can find a copy of that somewhere.

Comment: You can't expect everyone to have MS word installed, so this is not really a solution.

Comment: If you're writing shrinkwrap software you are correct but if you're writing in-house for a controlled environment where Word is part of the SOE you can rely on having Word.  Failing that you CAN rely on having Write & doing everything in RTF - Been there, done that, got the T-shirt, don't want to do it again BTW.  We need more information before we can definitively answer.

Comment: @mcottle I know this is uncouth but I was wondering if I could contact you about a parsing Delphi post you made on the SE stack exchange.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin Sure, ask away.

Comment: @mcottle Basically I'm in a situation fairly close to one you talked about where you wrote a parser for Delphi to re-write a legacy app and I was hoping I could get some feedback on my plan or get your notes on edge cases. Can you send me an email? Contact info in profile.